# Proper way to go about using Heroku and Git?

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

I've been having a lot of issues using Heroku and Git and am not sure I've been doing the steps properly, here is my process. Open Git Bash, then

```
heroku login
<enter in login>
cd ../../workspace/xkayak
git init
git add .
git commit -m "message"
heroku create
git push heroku master
```

This here above works, yet I want to have the ability to update this website by not deleting the app every single time then recreating it

Here was my attempt at updating it. Open Git Bash, then

```
heroku login
<enter in login>
cd ../../workspace/xkayak
git add .
git commit -m "update message"
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:xkayak
git push heroku master
```

Why didn't this work?
I attempted to delete the `.git` folder and add in a `git init` command

I was prompted with some `git pull` messages and errors and don't know what to do now.

Can anyone post a proper way to go about updating apps?

P.S. I am using node.js

Comment: Heroku node apps do a recreate every time. Behind the scenes it keeps a snapshot of your old versions just in case you want to go back. What exactly do you want to keep in the application directory between releases?

Comment: nothing really. Atleast not yet...

Comment: You only need to do a `git push heroku master` once you have committed changes. This is the node heroku tutorial https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#deploy-your-application-to-heroku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing too many steps in your update....

For creating a heroku project:

```
heroku login
<enter in login>
cd ../../workspace/xkayak
<do work>
git init
git add .
git commit -m "update message"
heroku create
git push heroku master
```

To update heroku project:

```
cd ../../workspace/xkayak
<do work>
git add .
git commit -m "update message"
git push heroku master
```

when you first ran `heroku create` git has stored the heroku remote.

You can run `git remote -v` to view all the remote copies of your local repo. often you'll use github.com as another remote.

Answer (score 0):

The following process should work for most people:

```
=============================
WHEN FIRST CREATING
--------------------------------------------
cd into_your_project
git init
git add .
git commit -m "my first commit"

heroku login
heroku create

git remote -v

##IF YOU HAVE ERRORS {
heroku git:remote -a falling-wind-1624
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add
ssh-add ~/.ssh/github_rsa
ssh-add -l
##IF YOU HAVE ERRORS }

git push heroku master
=============================
WHEN UPDATING
-------------------------------------------
git add .
git commit -m "my second commit"
git push heroku master
```